# iptables limits

Tags: iptables

We have a ubuntu set up as firewall (basic iptables), the thing is we have a netmask of 255.255.0.0 i.e almost possible 65531 addresses.

Since I want to monitor download traffic per IP, I need to make thousands of rules (I have a script that can do that) but will my server support that number of rules?

configuration:

```
Dell optiplex 7210    
core i3 2.6Ghz    
4GB RAM    
50GB HD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/479549/how-many-rules-can-iptables-support) I gather the theoretical limit would be around 38 million on 32 bit systems, so I think 64 bit systems would be much more. But again from the afore mentioned source any thing above `25,000 rules` say `27,000` would become a problem.

Issues are mainly memory usage on these systems with such a large number of `iptable rules`, it's suggested one can use:

1. `ipsets` from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/546806/how-many-iptables-block-rules-is-too-many), and
2. `geoip modules` for iptables from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53857/cant-add-large-number-of-rules-to-iptables) when targeting a country

Quote from a user (pdepartida) [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=3261):

> A couple of weeks ago i was getting massive port 80 requests to a 404 on my server, that were attached to my domain, so i could not just change the ip or whatever.
>
> I needed to block this bot requests and still have my apache up and running so i started to dynamically block through iptables. At the end of the first 24 hours i was already blocking over 22'000 distinct ip's. I had to upgrade my linode with 90 extra mb of RAM (from a linode 360) but everything else was fine!
>
> After a week i had already blocked over 53'000 different ips. Everything ran like a charm and was still able to keep apache running until eventually the bots stopped trying...
>
> By the way, i flushed up tables once a week, just in case.

So it really depends on your available memory.